# HLL to machine code

Tags: compiler-construction

If Assembly language is only a readable way of machine language then why HLLs are converted to assembly first and then to machine code . Shouldn't HLL directly converted to machine code ?

Comment: You should repost this on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ -- you will likely get more responses.

Answer (score 0):

What platform are you talking about?

.NET or Java assemblies have nothing in common with Assembler language besides the name.

While Assembler language might be thought of as of just a readable way of machine language, .NET assemblies (created by compiling high-level .NET language like C#) are just another programs in CIL (Common Intermediate Language), which is also high-level machine-independent language albeit not designed to be read or modified by human.

Answer (score 0):

Compiling in small discrete stages is simpler and cleaner than combining multiple passes together. Assembler is not only an abstraction over the machine code, it would also resolve the labels and literals.

You would not want to do this in your compiler backend alongside with instruction selection and register scheduling, since it is a totally independent pass. Of course, many compiler backends would contain their own assembler pass (i.e., all the JIT compilers) instead of serialising to a text stream and passing it to a separate assembler, but still it is a dedicated pass, and there is no point at all in fusing it with the other code generation passes.